# Angular requests datas missing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a little problem in my Angular's project.

When I make a  Get request from frontend, sometimes my request are perfect sometimes not. For exemple:

**When I ask for this:**

```
[HttpGet("fromfor/{userId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MessageDTO>>> GetMessagesFromForUsers(int userId)
        {
            var messages = await _context.Messages.ToListAsync();
            var messagesToReturn = new List<Message>();
            var destinations = await _context.Destinations.ToListAsync();

            if (messages == null)
                return NotFound();
            else
            {
                foreach (Message m in messages)
                {
                    if (m.AuthorId == userId)
                        messagesToReturn.Add(m);
                }
            }
            if (destinations == null)
                return NotFound();
            else
            {

                foreach (Destination d in destinations)
                {
                    if (d.UserId == userId)
                    {
                        var mess = await _context.Messages.Where(m => m.Id == d.MessageId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                        messagesToReturn.Add(mess);
                    }
                }
            }

            return messagesToReturn.ToDTO();

        }
```

**With this service :**

```
getMessagesFromForUsers(userId: number) {
        return this.http.get<Message[]>(`${this.baseUrl}api/messages/fromfor/${userId}`).pipe(
            map(res => res.map(m => new Message(m))));
    }
```

It is all fine I got all my datas sent back to front. (See photos at the end)

**But when I ask for:**

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MessageDTO>> GetOne(int id)
        {
            var mess = await _context.Messages.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (mess == null)
                return NotFound();
            return mess.ToDTO();
        }
```

**With this service :**

```
getMessageById(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<Message>(`${this.baseUrl}api/messages/${id}`).pipe(
            map(m => !m ? null : new Message(m)),
        );
    }
```

I got one data missing from backend. It destinations attribute....

I tried to understand but it's beyond my capacities for now, and I find nothing similar here to help me...

I can take more code lines, or some screens to show how my Models and DTO are but it's a lot of things to read.

Thanks a lot for reading and maybe helping me !

[image: Response from first request]

[image: Response from second request]

Comment: You will have more luck with a useful answer by asking the person(s) that wrote the original code.

Comment: I made the code, if you mean the person wich wrote all of this @fjc

Comment: Well, then you'll probably need to figure out that problem by debugging your code properly. We don't know how it works, we have no way of running it, and as it's not a clearly reproducible issue and it seems specific to your code, I don't think you'll get good help here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get destinations filled when you request the message you need to explicitly include it in your query :

```
 var mess = await _context
             .Messages.Include(r=> r.Destinations)
             .Where(m => m.Id == id)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: But how do you explain that my first query works and not the second ? I have destinations filled with forfrom request but not with single one.

I'll try this

Comment: @Yggdrasill because your first quey also loads the `Destinations` with this query : `var destinations = await _context.Destinations.ToListAsync();` once its loaded entity framework change tracker will address the values.

Comment: oh wow ok !!!! Didnt know that ! Sometimes it's hard to understand something under our eyes ! It's working ! Than'ks a lot !! And even if I'm playing drukharis (hope eldar is for 40k^^) u helped me =)